# What letters are used in this paper by Halin (1976)?

Tags: mathematics

I was trying to read an [older paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01917434) about treewidth by Halin (1976). He used different hand-written labels, obviously Sütterlin:
[image]

I assume the hand-written letters to be (from top to bottom and from left to right) "F*(n)", "C*(n)", "D*(n)". No I am poring over the next letter. Is it an "Y*(n)"? Or a "H*(n)"? Or even a strangely-written "E*(n)"?

Comment: The loop detail on the upper left suggests that it is a capital H rather than Y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's clear to me that the letters with * are capital Fraktur forms of F, C, D, and H, respectively, corresponding to the lower case "S-functions" f, c, d, and h, respectively.

I like this [cheat sheet](https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/fraktur), which gives the handwritten forms of the letter shapes.

Comment: +1 Back in the day (before TeX) mathematicians in certain fields would have to learn to read and write these.  Germans had an advantage, if they had learned these in school anyway.